# Is there any trace jit implementation based on LLVM?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

I couldn't find any, but I'd like to try my luck here.

Comment: What is the "trace jit"?

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple BF trace JIT: https://github.com/resistor/BrainFTracing (discussed at red: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/d74lg/i_wrote_an_llvmpowered_tracebased_jit_for_brainfck/).

It consists of interpreter with tracing (trace recording) and llvm IR emitter.